# How to make the table caption look smaller

Tags: captions, fontsize

I am new to the world of LaTeX and I am trying make my correlation table look nice.

My LaTeX code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}     
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{letterpaper}                          
\geometry{landscape}                        
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}            
\usepackage{graphicx}               
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{ Correlation Table}
\def\x{%
\begin{tabular}{rlllllllllllllllllllllllllll}
%blah blah blah
\end{tabular}
} 

\scalebox{0.12}{\x}
\end{document}
```

The scale box is to reduce the scale, in order to prevent the table from cutting off. I want to change the font size of the caption because otherwise the caption looks huge compared to the table (especially after the rescaling).
How can I make my table look nice with the caption?

Comment: If you have to scale the tabular down *that* much in order to make it fit on the page, maybe you should opt for a more efficient way of presenting the data to your readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\def\x{%
\begin{tabular}{rlllllllllllllllllllllllllll}
%blah blah blah
\end{tabular}%<<<<
}
```

It is better to use `\newcommand` rather than the TeX primitive `\def` in LaTeX, also you are missing a `%` as shown.  However you don't need to use a command definition here at all, you could just put the tabular directly in the argument to `\scalebox`. Or it is probably easier to use `\resizebox`. if you want the caption to scale similarly, include that in the scale.

Please always post *complete* documents that show the problem (and without spurious errors such as missing `\end{table}`

```
\documentclass{article}     
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{letterpaper}                          
\geometry{landscape}                        
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}            
\usepackage{graphicx}               
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\savebox{0}{%
\begin{tabular}{rlllllllllllllllllllllllllll}
blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&
blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah&blah
\end{tabular}}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\parbox{\wd0}{%
\caption{ Correlation Table}

\usebox{0}

}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This answers the question, but scaling text is generally a bad idea, it produces inconsistent font sizes, and here arbitrarily small text. It's normally better to use a standard font size such as `\small` and then choose a table format with an appropriate number of columns for that size.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you are doing this, but this can be a way.

Load the `caption` package and declare the `plain` caption style to be:

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{plain}{\scalebox{0.12}{#1#2#3\par}}
```

Also, you will need a very little caption separation:

```
\captionsetup{skip=0.1pt}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\geometry{landscape}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{plain}{\scalebox{0.12}{#1#2#3\par}}
\captionsetup{skip=0.1pt}

\newcommand\x{%
\begin{tabular}{lll}
blah & blah & blah
\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Correlation Table}
\scalebox{0.12}{\x}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result (3200x zoom):

[image]